# Angular Block Register Page

Tags: django, angular

I was Wonderring is there a way to make register url not working when user is logged in. I am use Frontend Angular And Backend Django

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Token/JWT use Angular guard.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private auth: AuthService
  ) { }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {

    if (this.service.isLoggedIn) {
      return this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

And in routes

```
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    canActivate: [LoginGuard],
  },
```

`isLoggedIn` in `AuthService` only checks if auth token exists.